# How to uniquely identify each cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, segue

I have a `UITableView` and I am trying to make a segue to another `viewcontroller`, I need the row number so that I can select a string from an array so that I can display this string in the next view controller, I have this code at the moment.

```
let tableFrontView = segue.destination as! FCTableFrontViewController
tableFrontView.frontText = path[FlashCardsTableViewCell.init().tag].flashCardFront
```

the `FlashCardsTableViewCell.init().tag` is currently returning an int for testing purposes though I am wanting to know what I can replace it with to get me the number of the row which was selected by the user.
Thanks

Comment: `UITableView` have `didSelectRowAt` method in which you can get the selected string from your Array by using `let strSelectedValue = arrData[indexPath.row]`

Answer (score 0):

Use TableView's delegate method  :

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
 // indetify cell using indexPath.row attribute
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let tableFrontView = segue.destination as! FCTableFrontViewController
    let selectedIndexPath = tblView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let selectedRow = (selectedIndexPath?.row)!
    print(selectedRow)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are writing the code snippet shown in `prepare(for:)`?

If that's the case, go to where you perform the segue, which is likely in the `didSelectedRowAtIndexPath` delegate method. If you don't have such a method, you should implement it.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTableFrontVC", sender: nil)
}
```

Replace whatever it is that you are passing as `sender` now, and replace that with `indexPath.row`.

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTableFrontVC", sender: indexPath.row)
```

Now in `prepare(for:)`, you can unwrap sender as an `Int`:

```
let tableFrontView = segue.destination as! FCTableFrontViewController
let rowSelected = sender as! Int
tableFrontView.frontText = path[rowSelected].flashCardFront
```